# Stopping current and Maxwell equation compliance

Tags: charge, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

**Preamble:** Mathematically, the divergence of an eddy field is zero, thus for the magnetic field
$$\nabla\cdot\nabla\times\boldsymbol B = \boldsymbol 0$$
and from the $\nabla\times\boldsymbol B$ Maxwell equation
$$\nabla\cdot \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) = 0 \ .$$
The integral of the above over any volume is $0$. So is a closed surface integral (Gauss integration theorem) of the divergence's argument, i.e. $\forall A$
$$\oint_A \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S = 0$$

**My thought experiment:** As closed surface I choose a sphere $A$ centered at the origin. I split the sphere into a left part $L$ and right part $R$, both open surfaces with $A = L \cup R$. Surfaces $L$ and $R$ have the same orientation such that
\begin{equation}
\int_L \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S
= \int_R \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S
\end{equation}
follows from
$$\oint_{L \cup R} \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S = 0  \ .$$
Now I assume all current $\boldsymbol J$ flowing into the sphere is coming from the $L$-side and then stops inside (in a symmetric pattern around the origin), causing an accumulation of charge and a non-zero $\partial \boldsymbol E / \partial t$.

**My problem:** Due to the above, $\partial \boldsymbol E / \partial t$ has to be radially symmetric and so 
\begin{equation}
\int_L \frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \cdot d\boldsymbol S
= \int_R \frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \cdot d\boldsymbol S
\end{equation}

> EDIT
>   With my declaration of $L$ and $R$ orientation, this should be \begin{equation} \int_L \frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \cdot d\boldsymbol S
> = -\int_R \frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \cdot d\boldsymbol S 
> \end{equation} 
>   which was my error and in hindsight renderes the rest
>   of the question void!
>
> /EDIT

are equal and what remains to fulfill the earlier flux equation is 
\begin{equation}
\int_L \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S
= \int_R \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S \ .
\end{equation}
But clearly we have
\begin{align}
\int_L \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S & \neq 0 \\
\int_R \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S & = 0 \ .
\end{align}

So, where is my flaw? What is the missing piece to save the equations? Is this a naive consideration and I need to use the full set of Maxwell equations and consider an EM wave being emitted by deceleration of charge, thus yielding other sources of $\partial \boldsymbol E / \partial t$? Or include the cause of the stopping current in terms of an electric field?

Comment: If $J$ is flowing, then I believe $\int_R \vec{J} \cdot d\vec{S} \neq 0$. If the charge is accumulanting it's got to get to the right side somehow.

Comment: Why does $\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$ have to be radially symmetric?

Comment: @QuantimBrick If I assume all current to stop inside, there is no flux through the right side.

Comment: @GDumphart Yes there is. If the material is accumulating current (and it is, since you're injecting current in it from the left side), then, from the fact that this accumulation is symmetric, it needs to flow to the right side, too.

Comment: @BySymmetry I required the charges to stop in a symmetric around and close to the origin. Or theoretically exactly at the origin if you prefer.

Comment: @QuantumBrick If I understand you right, then what you assume is the steady current assumption $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol J = 0$ from magnetostatics. There, the current density flux through all open surfaces with common border would be the same, like you say. For the electrodynamics case $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol J = -\partial \rho/\partial t$, that assumption is wrong and Maxwell's displacement current joins the party, and my question is from this domain.

Comment: That's not what I was saying, I guess. But I believe the question was answered.

Comment: @QuantumBrick Yes but you have current going in one side and not the other, so the situation still is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your parition $A=L\cup R$, we have that
\begin{gather}&\oint_A \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S = 0 &\implies\\
&\int_L \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S
+ \int_R \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S =0&\implies\\
&\int_L \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S
= -\int_R \left( \boldsymbol J + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\boldsymbol S
\end{gather}
so the fluxes are not equal, they are **opposite**. So, although
\begin{equation}
\int_L \frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} d\boldsymbol S
= \int_R \frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \cdot d\boldsymbol S
\end{equation}
holds, this has no contradiction to
\begin{equation}
\int_L \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S
\neq \int_R \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S
\end{equation}
We only have that
\begin{gather}&\int_L \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S+\int_L \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} d\boldsymbol S=-\int_R \frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} \cdot d\boldsymbol S&\implies\\
&\int_L \boldsymbol J \cdot d\boldsymbol S=-\int_A \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E}{\partial t} d\boldsymbol S\end{gather}

Comment: You skipped or misunderstood my declaration of $L$ and $R$ orientation when they're not joint (no worries, it's hard without a sketch). I took that scheme from here: http://users.ox.ac.uk/~math0391/EMlectures.pdf - very start of chapter 3, Eq (3.2). But you are totally right about me making a stupid sign boo boo, which solves my problem. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I imagined that this could be the case, but I thought that there was a bigger chance to be a mistake here, than in the radially symmetric statement that the left and right fluxes were equal.

Comment: Rightfully so, I didn't emphasize my unnecessary assumption enough.